# Aggregate dataframe in rolling blocks of 3 rows

Tags: r, aggregation, rolling-computation

I have the following data frame as an example

```
   df <- data.frame(score=letters[1:15], total1=1:15, total2=16:30)
> df
   score total1 total2
1      a      1     16
2      b      2     17
3      c      3     18
4      d      4     19
5      e      5     20
6      f      6     21
7      g      7     22
8      h      8     23
9      i      9     24
10     j     10     25
11     k     11     26
12     l     12     27
13     m     13     28
14     n     14     29
15     o     15     30
```

I would like to `aggregate` my data frame by sum by grouping the rows having different name, i.e.

```
  groups  sum1 sum2
 'a-b-c'  6     51
 'c-d-e'  21    60
etc
```

All the given answers to this kind of question assume that the strings repeat in the row.

The usual `aggregate` function that I use to obtain the summary delivers a different result:

```
aggregate(df$total1, by=list(sum1=df$score %in% c('a','b','c'), sum2=df$score %in% c('d','e','f')), FUN=sum)
   sum1  sum2  x
1 FALSE FALSE 99
2  TRUE FALSE  6
3 FALSE  TRUE 15
```

Comment: Also, most people avoid using `c` as a variable name since it is the name of the most common function.

Comment: Typo in my earlier comment. Your first example has overlapping groups, `"a-b-c"` and `"c-d-e"`, with `c` in both groups. Your second example has non-overlapping groups `"a-b-c"` and `"d-e-f"`. Which do you want? Is it just every three rows you want, or do you want to specify letter combinations?

Comment: Do you want to aggregate every N=3 rows under one name? overlapping like 'a-b-c', 'c-d-e',... or disjoint like 'a-b-c', 'd-e-f',...? and how to handle any raggedness at the end if nrows is not a multiple of 3? PS I edited your dataframe name from the confusing `c` to the unambiguous `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a tidyverse solution, here is one possibility:

```
df <- data.frame(score=letters[1:15], total1=1:15, total2=16:30)

df %>%
  mutate(groups = case_when(
    score %in% c("a","b","c") ~ "a-b-c",
    score %in% c("d","e","f") ~ "d-e-f"
  )) %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)
```

returns

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  groups total1 total2
  <chr>   <int>  <int>
1 a-b-c       6     51
2 d-e-f      15     60
3 <NA>       99    234
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a "groups" column with the category value.

```
df$groups = NA
```

and then define each group like this:

```
df$groups[df$score=="a" | df$score=="b" | df$score=="c" ] = "a-b-c"
```

Finally aggregate by that column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works for any sized data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(score=letters[1:15], total1=1:15, total2=16:30)

# I'm adding a row to demonstrate that the grouping pattern works when the 
# number of rows is not equally divisible by 3.
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(score = letters[16], total1 = 16, total2 = 31))

# A vector that represents the correct groupings for the data frame.
groups <- c(rep(1:floor(nrow(df) / 3), each = 3), 
            rep(floor(nrow(df) / 3) + 1, nrow(df) - length(1:(nrow(df) / 3)) * 3))

# Your method of aggregation by `groups`. I'm going to use `data.table`.
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, group := groups]

aggDT <- dt[, list(score = paste0(score, collapse = "-"), 
          total1 = sum(total1), total2 = sum(total2)), by = group][
            , group := NULL]
aggDT

   score total1 total2
1: a-b-c      6     51
2: d-e-f     15     60
3: g-h-i     24     69
4: j-k-l     33     78
5: m-n-o     42     87
6:     p     16     31
```